# How to Start-Job in order to add multiple entries into HashTable

Tags: powershell

Currently, I'm reading through thousands of .csv's that may have multiple rows showing up multiple times. I only need a subset of the columns in my output. I'm also keeping a count of the number of occurrences of all data in the second column.

Going through thousands of lines for thousands of .csv's is very time consuming, so I was wondering what's the best approach to updating a single HashTable through the use of `Start-Job`

Comment: In my opinion you should consider runspaces instead of jobs. More complicated, but easier to sync. Or are you hoping to distribute the work load across multiple computers?

Comment: This function may help you: https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/Invoke-Parallel

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Oh? Never considered runspaces. What keywords besides "runspaces" do you recommend searching for in order to get the job done? Thanks!

Comment: I learned about them from FoxDeploy [here](https://foxdeploy.com/2016/05/17/part-v-powershell-guis-responsive-apps-with-progress-bars/).